# LaTeX file works on Windows 11 but not on Ubuntu 22.04, why?

Tags: ubuntu, linux, tabularray

I have one file which can run on Windows 11 successfully but fails to run on Ubuntu 22.04. What is the reason for that? Ii might be about the `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabularray,ctex,siunitx,amsmath}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
        \vspace{-1.7cm}
        \begin{talltblr}[
            caption={e},
            entry={e},
            label={tab:e},
            note{$\S$}={$\text{www}=\dfrac{\mathrm{HI}-[\text{HI(weee)}]}{\mathrm{rqr}}$}
            ]{
                colspec={c *{4}{X[c,2.4em]} *{2}{X[c,3em]} X[c,2em] *{2}{X[c,si={table-format=1.3e-1}]}},colsep=2pt,rowsep=0pt,vline{8}={1-2}{dashed},
            }
            \toprule
            1&3&2&4&\SetCell[c=2]{c}{{{HI\TblrNote{$\S$}\\123}}}&&&4&\\
    \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

On Windows 11:
[image]

On Ubuntu 22.04:
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu/windows makes no difference, but you will have an older version on one system. add \listfiles to the preamble and compare the list at the end of the log in each case

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In Windows 11, `This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.8.8)  28 AUG 2022 13:48
entering extended mode`; in Ubuntu, `This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.8.27)  28 AUG 2022 13:48`. How should I repair it?

Comment: the version of xetex is also not relevant what is almost certainly different is the version of `tabularray` that is a new, actively devloped package that gets new features _all the time_

Comment: the log on the working version will show a full path to `tabularray.sty` copy that file to the directory with your document on linux, that will probably work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I see. I once installed TexLive by `sudo apt-get install textlive-full` in `Ubuntu`, by which it didn't install the last version of LaTex, so the version of `tabularray.sty` is too low. Now I had deleted the installation and reinstalled the LaTeX throught `https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html`. And this error is gone. Another point is that: after reinstall the TexLive, we need to reinstall TexWorks and TexStudio, or these two apps will not work right.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall editors. You need to setup the changed PATH correctly. It is NOT enough to just add it to `.bashrc`, especially if you start the editor from a menu or double click. Add it to `.profile` as well, log out and in again (`.profile is only read at login)

Comment: @daleif I am a newbie of Ubuntu. I don't know how to modify `.profile` and what it is. Changing `.bashra` have made me very very tired. The Ubuntu is very difficult for newbies. I remember your idea and will try it in the future when I know Ubuntu more.

Comment: It's described many places online. It lives in the same folder where you found `.profile`. You can even find answers on this site that describe all the steps.

Comment: glad you got it working but you re installed  many gigabytes of data to update a few k of .sty file literally millions more data than you needed to change

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to update one `.sty` file after I installed the LaTeX by `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: not via apt but as I wrote above you don't need to install anything, most likely you could just copy `tabularray.sty` from your windows machine and place it with your document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am a little afraid of Ubuntu, so I can't imagine this way. I will try in the future.

Comment: If you say so, seems odd that you find copying one small text file in your own user acount area scary, but assuming admin privilges with sudo and installing gigbytes of application data less so

Comment: One changes automatically, one is by myself. I fear making it broken. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your TeX Live on Ubuntu. In my Ubuntu, it works well with `xelatex`.

```shell
tlmgr update --all --self
```

or

```shell
sudo tlmgr update --all --self
```

### ADD

It is recommended to refer to [Quick install - TeX Live - TeX Users Group](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) to install TeX Live.

Comment: I install texlive by `sudo apt-get install textlive-full`, so I can't update *texlive*. The *texlive* I installed is not the last version which only contains the old version of *tabularray*. I try to install the last version of  *texlive* on Ubuntu 22.04, but there is error: *TLUtils.pm*. It is difficult. May you tell me how did you install your *LaTeX*?

Comment: It shows: `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`

Comment: On Ubuntu, if you have no disk space problems, the best option in my opinion is to install a portable texlive in your home directory along with the minimal system installation of Tex/LaTeX

Comment: @Yzeng when you install latex via `apt` you are at the mercy of your Linux dist when it comes to latex package updates. Most often than not, once a new texlive version is added to say, Ubuntu, it is not updated. Ubuntu even changes `tlmgr` such that you cannot use it to update latex (as that would bring it out of sync with apt).

Comment: @Rmano I reinstalled the LaTeX with `https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html`, and it works right now. It is not good to install it by `sudo apt-get install textlive-full`, whose version may be too low.

Comment: @daleif You are right. So I deleted the all files about LaTeX and reinstalled LaTeX through `https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html`. Now, all things are right.

Comment: @Y.zeng I'm very sorry, I didn't notice the message in time. It is not recommended to install TeX Live with `apt`. It is best to install TeX Live according to [Quick install - TeX Live - TeX Users Group](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). Then update all packages.

Comment: @Clara Thank you, this is not urgent. I thought the official Ubuntu one would be the best, but I was wrong.

Comment: @Y.zeng I did not study it deeply. I guess TeX Live officials do not pay much attention to maintaining the packages on `apt`. Therefore, it may lag, and you can get updates in time by using `tlmgr`. In addition, you can even install multiple versions of TeX Live. You can easily use different versions of TeX Live by switching path.

Comment: @Clara it isn't really the TeXLive officials that adds the packages to `apt`. There might be one that is more up to date in Debian unstable, but I don't think Ubuntu take any of those.

Comment: @Clara Maybe. It is not convenient to install software and drives in Linux. I installed *Debian* in my **VMware**, but I can run your code in *Terminal*. What may be the reason?

Comment: @Y.zeng TeX Live has it own package manager, i.e., tlmgr. You can run `which tlmgr` find its path. I always install TeX Live use the script on tug.org, not `apt`.

Comment: @Clara I reinstalled the LaTeX as *tug.org* successfully, but I can run your code which contains `tlmgr`. What is the reason?

Comment: @Y.zeng I am confused about your description. I wonder if you misunderstood my meaning. Let me rephrase it again. TeX Live package management can be performed by `tlmgr` when TeX Live is installed according to tug.org's instructions. I haven't used `apt` to install TeX Live, so I don't know if I can use `tlmgr`.

Comment: @Clara Before I asked this question, I had installed LaTeX by `apt`. After seeing your answer, I know it is better to install LaTeX with *tug.org*, and I deleted my Ubuntu in my VMware. Then I installed the *Debian 11* in which I installed the LaTeX, by the way the *tug.org* recommends. So now I should run your code successfully in my *Debian 11*, but I ran it fail.

Comment: @Y.zeng I run `which tex` and `which tlmgr` on Ubuntu, I got `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex` and `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`. How about yours?

Comment: @Clara Ours are the same. But I run with errors: `z@zu:~$ which tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex
z@zu:~$ which tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
z@zu:~$ sudo tlmgr update --all --self
[sudo] password for z: 
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!`

Comment: @Y.zeng Maybe you can run without `sudo`.

Comment: @Clara Yes. When should I use `sudo` and when shouldn't I?

Comment: @Y.zeng In [tlmgr - TeX Live - TeX Users Group](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html), if you installed MacTeX, precede the commands below with sudo, since MacTeX installs as root. I think if you install TeX Live as root, `sudo` is necessary.

Comment: @Clara Thanks a lot. I know now.